# SMTP protocol issue with Zend_Mail

Tags: php, zend-framework, smtp, zend-mail

I'm trying to send some emails via GMail SMTP and the CC and BCC lines are not receiving the email. I've tested GMail SMTP with Evolution (Linux email client), which works fine, though I could not get a raw dump of the communication because it's via SSL.

Here's the communication log from Zend_Mail:

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP 22sm2669783yxe.39
EHLO localhost
250-mx.google.com at your service, [67.152.160.2]
250-SIZE 35651584
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
[removed]
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
[removed]
235 2.7.0 Accepted
MAIL FROM:[removed]
250 2.1.0 OK 22sm2669783yxe.39
RCPT TO:<zf-mail-test-1@mailinator.com>
250 2.1.5 OK 22sm2669783yxe.39
RCPT TO:<zf-mail-test-2@mailinator.com>
250 2.1.5 OK 22sm2669783yxe.39
RCPT TO:<zf-mail-test-3@mailinator.com>
250 2.1.5 OK 22sm2669783yxe.39
DATA
354  Go ahead 22sm2669783yxe.39
From: [removed]
To: zf-mail-test-1@mailinator.com
Cc: zf-mail-test-2@mailinator.com
Subject: My Test Subject
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2009 14:21:49 -0600
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0

My test body
.
250 2.0.0 OK 1260217313 22sm2669783yxe.39
```

I don't know enough about the SMTP protocol to figure out what Zend_Mail isn't doing that it needs to be doing for CC/BCC lines to work.

Comment: This looks about right. Do the `zf-mail-test-*@mailinator.com` addresses all receive the email if they are the primary recipient (i.e., not CC'd or BCC'ed) - that is, if you send the emails one-at-a-time?

Comment: Yes. The general consensus I got outside of SO was that all the mailinator.com addresses are basically aliases to one large mailbox and their SMTP server is not delivering duplicate emails to the same mailbox. The same behavior applies to mailbox+whatever@gmail.com. +whatever is an alias to the mailbox and thus, only one copy is delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: http://forums.codewalkers.com/pear-packages-47/email-bcc-header-confusion-840705.html

In particular:

> With SMTP, all recipients must be
>   listed as param 1 in send, and the
>   contents of the To/Cc/Bcc headers have
>   no effect on what gets sent - they are
>   just receiver information.

In a project that I did a while back, I had to send the email to each BCC recipient individually.